# How to use 1TB HDD as main drive when mint is installed on 24GB SSD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, linux-mint

I have linuxmint installed on a 24GB SSD on my laptop. The laptop also has a 1TB HDD installed internally. I need help getting permission to write to the HDD, and use it as the main drive for file storage. Currently the drive is viewed as a "removable drive" and when I try to view the permissions it says "The permissions of "HDD" could not be determined". The drive is mounted and everything but I still can't save anything on it or create any files or directories. I am running Mint 13 on a lenovo laptop. If needed I can post results of fdisk -l. The drive is formatted in ext3 with 1 partition taking up the entire drive. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How is it that the drive is mounted but you can't write to it ?  Do you have it mounted read-only, is the mount of the drive owned by root and you don't have permissions to write to it ?  Conceptually it should be quite straightforward to mount the drive - mounting an external drive is no different to mouning an internal one.

Comment: I just tried to unmount and it gave me the error "Only root may unmount drive /dev/sdb". I followed a tutorial to format the drive and in the process it instructed me to create a "media" drive and mount the drive to that. I'm not assuming that is incorrect, and if so how should I proceed to unmount the drive and then mount it again?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue - you are obviously not root, and I'm surmising that the permissions on the drive are such that only root can access it.  If you are not overly fussed about security, you can make yourself the owner of the drive as follows:  1.  Get root access (this will vary from distro to distro, but in a terminal typing "sudo su" or "sudo /bin/bash" often works.  Then change the ownership of the mount point and all sub-paths in the drive to you - so if the mount point is /media/MYDISK1 you would use the command chown -R yourusername /media/MYDISK1